# How can I remove the status bar in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

So basically I want to remove the status bar of my app and I've found no solution. I don't want to make my app fullscreen I just want that part to be transparent and have more space for my app. I tried changing the color of the status bar to transparent but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated! I will attach a photo with the part that I want to remove to be more specific.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw5Tk.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to make your app full screen, you should make the status bar transparent. So add this line to your theme.xml file:

```
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Therefore, your theme.xml should be something like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: it's transparent now but it has a dark tint to it, could you tell me how to remove that?

Comment: It is for making the status bar, including time, battery level, etc. More clear to the user. As far as I know, you can not remove them unless you make the application full screen.

Comment: Yes , this makes transparent status bar but does not hide. To  remove only status bar,You should use the new WindowInsetsControllerCompat Immersive screen api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WindowInsetsControllerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat) API to acheive this

You can try this function . Add this in `onCreate()` of activity.

```
private fun hideStatusBar() {
    WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window,window.decorView).apply {
        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    }
}
```

[Click here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive#type) to read more